# Amazon EMR how to find out when job is finish?

Tags: amazon-s3, hive, emr

I'm using Amazon Elastic MapReduce Ruby (http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/2264) to run my hive job. Is there a way to know when the job is done? Right now all I could think of is the keep running emrclient with "--list --active" but I'm hoping there is a better way to do this.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You may also get to know this from the [aws console](http://aws.amazon.com/console)'s EMR section.

If your concern is to terminate the cluster once your job is done then while launching the cluster don not use the option `--stay-alive`. Or alternatively, you can have a script which would poll for the current status of the running cluster and terminate it once it gets to 'waiting' state.

I do not think there is another way.

Comment: I do not have --stay-alive flag on. I want to know when the job is finish because I can transfer data back out of s3 immediately. Currently, there is a pulling script to do this. It's not very "pretty" but I think that will do for now. Thank you :)